# Gmail API: Recipient of the email will see red warning about the safety of the email

Tags: gmail-api

We have a problem with all emails sent via our Gmail API App.
All of them deliver with a warning about the safety of the email

> This message seems dangerous. Many people marked similar messages as phishing scams, so this might contain unsafe content. Avoid clicking links, downloading attachments, or replying with personal information.

[image: Screenshot of the warning message]

This happens only when sending an email through our `Gmail API` but when sent via `SMTP` will deliver the message without any warning.

This warning message appears on all emails sent via our Gmail API Application, no matter if the sender is a Google workspace user or a free Gmail user.

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: This commonly comes from the content of the mail. The algorithms estimated based on some criteria that your email resembles a lot emails sent usually by phishers. So it warns you about this mail in your inbox.

Comment: You may want to check the comments & findings on an answer from this similar post at [Gmail: This message seems dangerous](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/143280)